# What ways can a University Student get involved in Trajectory Design?

Tags: trajectory, mission-design, astrodynamics, trajectory-design

As a physics student (not an engineer) in India, I can't seem to find a lot of opportunities to involve myself in what I find most appealing about what I'm studying in University i.e. astrodynamics. Most government space programs are either highly secretive or are only willing to provide term employment opportunities to people late in their careers. Apart from doing courses on edX and dabbling with some code on python, is there no tangible alternative where I can involve myself in real missions with real people??

Comment: Does your school have some sort of Aerospace Club that does rocketry? It's not going to be anything orbital, but it would be a great way to get your foot in the door and meet some people in the industry.